# localhost server to javascript data transmission

Tags: javascript, applet

My appologies , i am new in java and javascript. 
I have Java applet server in my local host. I want to send data from this applet server ( lets say x,y,zz) to web application. The web application is in JavaScript function.

Is it possible to send data from my local host of applet to javascript.

I am really stuck in this situation. If it can happen , what function can do it...will be great help

Comment: *"..Java applet server.."*  I've heard of Java based servers, and dealt with/written hundreds of applets, but what on Earth is an 'applet server'?  Is it something that serves applets?  An applet that serves requests?  Something else..?

Comment: @ Andrew THompson , My apologies for the world , actually its  server written in java( applet) . Sorry for my language..
yes !! I want the idea and good guide for this...could u plz tell me what would be the best idea or methodology for my this purpose....hopping for the answer ..thank you

Comment: *"actually its server written in java( applet)"*  Why would someone try to make an applet that is a server?  Sounds like complete nonsense to me.  Please spell words like 'you' and 'please' properly.

Answer (score 0):

the basic function in javascript would be XMLHTTPRequest. If you never heard of it, try making some research about that.

Hope it helps.

edit: mozilla docs would be a good start point https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLHttpRequest

also see some doc about Ajax techniques https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: @ user309301 , I am going to see those two links send by u. and thank you very much for you answer and information. I have one confusion...
if i use AJAX and XMLHTTPRequest, will that be able to update my data of localhost in webapplication (javascript) instantly?

Comment: well for instant communication websocket would help you, but i have never used it. try looking https://www.websocket.org/index.html for some more info.

hope it helps.